# Splitting Formula using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have already generated formulas and stored it in database.Now,when I want to use formulas,I select one formula from autocomplete list say for example :

> abc=((bbc*40%)/cbc)+52

now ,I want to split this formula and fetch bbc,cbc values from database and calculate answer.How can I split this formula and separate out operators and operands using jQuery?

Comment: Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with regex to get only things you need.

Comment: So you want to get `abc`, `bbc` and `cbc` or replace them with the values? You could do `'abc=((bbc*40%)/cbc)+52'.match(/\w{3}/g,'')` to get the 3 values you want.

Comment: I want to get bbc,cbc and not want to replace with values...and they are not only of 3 characters,can be abcc,bbbcddd,xyzzzzzzzz,jj etc.

Comment: This isn't a job for Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am succeed in splitting formula by following way,

```
var expression = "((bbc*40%)/cbc)+52".replace(/[^A-Z]+/gi, "#").replace(/[\.]/g, "");

var operators = expression.split("#").filter(function(n){
    return n
});

for(var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++){
    console.log("Operator"+i+" :"+operators[i]);
}
```

May this helpful for someone...